# Permanent template other than Normal and document's own

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have several docm documents which are the same apart from some cosmetic differences. The documents are run by different users - who have their own normal.dotms. I have set up a common dotm where I have stored common macros - the documents have the same buttons with the same names . (The documents are cloned initially). Each document has a Doc_Open which sets the dotm to the common dotm. However when I click one of the document buttons it executes the document's own version of the relevant routine and not that in the common dotm. I want one common dotm for all of these documents and all different users.

Michael

CommandButton1_Click uses the document's OWN dotm and not the common dotm which I thought I had set with Doc_Open.

[image]

Comment: Please do not post pictures of your code. Post your actual code instead in your question (not in the comments) so people can copy/paste it if they want to.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the code from the template to be used you first need to remove the code from the document then save as docx.

Instead of attaching the template in code you could manually attach the template then save the document. The link to the template will be maintained

Optionally you could also set the location of the template as the Workgroup templates folder (File | Options | Advanced | General | File Locations) for each user. I believe this can be done by Group Policy, though it is probably named Shared Templates (as it is in the registry)